# Use same collection with two symfony projects and FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

We currently have a Symfony2 project, with FOSUser for user management.
We want to develop a second symfony project using the same database. So we have installed FOSUser and we want to authenticate with the same users.

It's impossible to connect with a user of project A on project B, and vice versa. Each time the message "Invalid credentials" is displayed. Is this normal? My classes both extend the FOS BaseUser, and call the parent construct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was a bad value for `security.encoders.FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface` field in `app/config/security.yml`.